# Conditional modification of amsart proof environment

Tags: conditionals, amsart

It would like to modify the proof environment of amsart in such a way that if a boolean variable, say `solution` is set to true in the preamble of the document, then the environment works as usual, but otherwise `\begin{proof} content \end{proof}` has no effect (i.e. is not printed). Is there a way to do this using etoolbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with `etoolbox`, but with `comment`:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{comment}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pr@@fon{%
  \includecomment{proof}%
  \let\proof\savedproofenv
  \let\proofon\@empty}
\newcommand\proofoff{%
  \ifx\proofon\@empty
    \let\savedproofenv\proof
    \excludecomment{proof}%
    \let\proofon\pr@@fon
  \fi}
\newcommand*\proofon{}%

\proofon

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  A proof that is typeset
\end{proof}

\proofoff
\begin{proof}
  A proof that is removed
\end{proof}

\proofon
\begin{proof}
  Another proof that is typeset
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Many thanks! Also, apologies, I have not made myself clear. The boolean variable is set in the preamble of the document.

Comment: @220284 You're welcome! You can move `\proofon` and `\proofoff` to the preamble of the document.  I put them in the middle just to show that they work

Comment: Great, will give it a shot!

Comment: Hm, if I put `\proofoff` in the preamble it works fine, but if I put `\proofon` it get the error that the proof environment is undefined.

Comment: @220284 Indeed, `\proofon` assumed `\proofoff` was used somewhere.  I edited my answer with a more robust version

Comment: Great, many thanks!